# jQuery - Form submission General Questionaire with Eval()

Tags: php, jquery, eval, form-submit

I use jquery's $.ajax() AP to send data to the server for validation.
(not on all forms, but those that do need more server-side validating)

Therefore, my serverside script receives the POSTED data, and does it's validation magic.
IF all data is validated, then I simply return the number "1", otherwise I return a zero "0"

form.html

```
<form class="systemform" id="testform">
   <input type="text" name="emailaddy" id="emailaddy" value="me@me.com" />
   <input type="submit" name="button" id="272746866" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("form.systemform").submit(function(){
      var formid = $(this).attr("id");
      var allFormValues = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({ url:"validate.php",
               data:allFormValues+"&formId="+formid,
               success:function(response){
                   if(response == "0"){ alert("invalid data"); }
                   if(response == "1"){ alert("data validated"); }

               }
       });return false;

});
</script>
```

---

```
<?php
    // validate.php

      /* validate the serialized data here */


      die("1"); // if everything checks out
    ?>
```

I'm very interested to hear other opinions/strategies on this method of validating form data.
The benefit is that there is no browser refresh.
But now I'm curious about what is best to perform after the validation.

Currently, the code above doesn't do too much.  So in the `success` portion of the $.ajax API, I have the eval() method waiting to take direction from the server-side script.

```
success:function(response){
    eval(response); return false;
}
```

The eval() gives more flexibility from the server, by passing a js function or command back.

2 die() examples:

```
<?php
//validation.php

die('alert("your email is incorrect");');  
die('$("selector").html("fix this part");');
?>
```

I know someone will want to say something about the eval(), and that it's insecure.  I'd like to hear it.  And I'd like to know why.  (it's good for all of us)  But please be detailed with some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is potentially insecure at all times because it can execute any JS at all and makes it easy to perform an attack on users.  Imagine that a hacker has the ability to execute any script and can send a malicious URL or the lick to a user.  If they use a particular input value, they could get your server to emit this:

```
die('window.location.href = "http://evilsite.com"');
```

Moreover, there should be no coupling between your client and server implementations at all.  There may be dependency on some element names, but not on the code.  You will actually lose flexibility when you try to integrate php code and JavaScript.  If `eval` is really more flexible, it could be an indication that you might want to rethink how you handle things on the client side.

As for doing server side validation vs. client side you always need to do both separately.  It is completely trivial to circumvent any sort of client side security you may have.  The only reason to have it is for user convenience (by avoiding page reloads, highlighting affected fields, etc.) but you *need* to do server side validation as well to protect yourself.

The only reason I can see to use ajax for validation is if you need to check some value from the DB (for example: see if a username is already taken).  I wouldn't use ajax to validate things like required fields.

Comment: I can see the die() holding a malicious url, but wouldn't the hacker need access to the php server script to pass such a thing?

Comment: @coffeemonitor not necessarily; they could post some value to your script that could get it to emit that value back.  It would be a little weird/extreme, but why take unnecessary risks?